# T-SQL Retrieve Last 6 Weeks Data to the Previous Saturday

Tags: date, t-sql, where-clause

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM FactSalesDetail
WHERE TradingDate >= DATEADD(ww, -6, (Select MAX([TradingDate]) From FactSalesDetail))
ORDER BY TradingDate
```

Can anyone advise how I can convert the above WHERE Clause from retrieving the last 6 weeks data from Max Date in my Fact Table to the last 6 weeks to the Previous Saturday?

So as of Today that would Saturday 1st Jan and then back 6 weeks from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the current weekday can get you last Saturday.
And if you bring @@DATEFIRST into the equation then it won't depend on the DATEFIRST setting.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM FactSalesDetail
WHERE TradingDate >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, -6, DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()))%7, 
GETDATE())))
  AND TradingDate <= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()))%7, 
GETDATE()))
ORDER BY TradingDate
```

**Test snippet for date range**

> ```
> SET DATEFIRST 7;
>
> SELECT 
>   datename(weekday, date_now) AS weekday_now, date_now
> , datename(weekday, date1) AS wd1, date1
> , datename(weekday, date2) AS wd2, date2 
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT 
>       CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS date_now
>     , CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, -6, DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()))%7, 
> GETDATE()))) AS date1
>     , CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()))%7, 
> GETDATE())) AS date2
> ) q
> ```

> 

| weekday_now | date_now | wd1 | date1 | wd2 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tuesday | 2022-01-04 | Saturday | 2021-11-20 | Saturday | 2022-01-01 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c25ad810032c9da8c5e65ccc9ce5be7)*

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Cool, then I guess you can approve your first answer on SO.